# How can I improve my method for parsing lz4 compressed json?

Tags: python, json, algorithm, unicode, lz4

I'm parsing very large (5GB to **2TB**) compressed json files and storing some data into csv files with the below algorithm. It works, but is the opposite of efficient due to having three nested loops.

I'm also unsure of the cost of a few lines of code due to my unfamiliarity with the json and yaml libraries provided by python:

```
k = yaml.load(json.dumps(v))
```

If you didn't notice, I already called a `yaml.load()` function 
above that line with:

`header = yaml.load(json.dumps(header))`

It seems that I had to call the function twice because the inner leaves(values) of the keys from `header` were interpreted as strings.

When I simply print out the value of v in this line: `for k, v in header.iteritems():`, the output generally looks like one of these lines:

```
[{'value': ['4-55251088-0 0NNN RT(1535855435726 0) q(0 -1 -1 -1) r(0 -1)'], 'key': 'x_iinfo'}]
[{'value': ['timeout=60'], 'key': 'keep_alive'}, {'value': ['Sun, 02 Sep 2018 02:30:35 GMT'], 'key': 'date'}]
[{'value': ['W/"12765-1490784752000"'], 'key': 'etag'}, {'value': ['Sun, 02 Sep 2018 02:27:16 GMT'], 'key': 'date'}]
[{'value': ['Sun, 02 Sep 2018 02:30:32 GMT'], 'key': 'date'}]
```

so basically, if in our file there is a category called 'unknown' which is a json tree including everything without a specific category.

**Is there a better way to get all of these values without slowing the algorithm down by adding two more loops?**

Full method source:

```
def convertJsonHeadersToCSV(jsonFilePath, CSVFilePath,portNum, protocol):
  try:
    bodyPattern = re.compile('<(html|!DOCTYPE).*$', re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE)
    csvFile = open(CSVFilePath, 'w')
    print("Converting " + protocol + " file to csv, please wait...")
    spinner.start()
    csvWriter = unicodecsv.writer(csvFile)
    csvWriter.writerow(['ip', 'date', 'protocol', 'port', 'data'])
    chunk_size = 128 * 1024 * 1024
    with lz4.frame.open(jsonFilePath, 'r') as f:
      for line in f:
        try:
          text = ""
          jsonData = json.loads(line)
          ts = jsonData['timestamp'][:10]
          ip = jsonData['ip']
          data = jsonData['data']['http']
          if 'response' in data:
            if 'headers' in data['response']:
              header = jsonData['data']['http']['response']['headers']
              header = yaml.load(json.dumps(header))
              for k, v in header.iteritems():
                if 'unknown' in k:
                  #print(v)
                  k = yaml.load(json.dumps(v))
                  for i in k:
                    #print(str(i['key']) + ": "+str(i['value']) + "\r\n")
                    text = text + str(str(i['key']) + ": "+str(i['value']) + "\r\n")
                else:
                  text = text + str(str(k) + ": "+str(v) + "\r\n")
              #csvWriter.writerow([ip, ts, protocol, portNum, text])

        except:#sometimes will run into a unicode error, still working on handling this exception.
          pass
    csvFile.close()
    spinner.stop()
    print("Completed conversion of " + protocol + " file.")
  except Exception as ex:
    spinner.stop()
    traceback.print_exc()
    print("An error occurred while converting the file, moving on to the next task...")
```

Comment: the culprit is probably this:`text = text + str(str(i['key']) + ": "+str(i['value']) + "\r\n")` string concatenation is very inefficient in python when the strings start to be big. Is that the case?

Comment: It does tend to get pretty big, should I just append to the file directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what would speed this up hugely for sure would be to stop using `text` as a string, because those lines:

```
    text = text + str(str(i['key']) + ": "+str(i['value']) + "\r\n")
else:
  text = text + str(str(k) + ": "+str(v) + "\r\n")
```

are performing a *string concatenation*. Since strings are immutable, a new copy must be done each time (even with `text +=` instead of `text = text +`, so this isn't of any help), and the bigger the string to copy, the slower (quadratic complexity).

It would be better to:

- define `text` as an empty list
- append to the list
- use `"".join` in the end

so

```
 for line in f:
    try:
      text = []   # define an empty list at start
      jsonData = json.loads(line)
```

then (using `str?format` would also be an improvement here, but that's minor)

```
       text.append(str(str(i['key']) + ": "+str(i['value']) + "\r\n"))
    else:
      text.append(str(str(k) + ": "+str(v) + "\r\n"))
```

and in the end "mutate" `text` into a string like this:

```
text = "".join(text)
```

or just

```
csvWriter.writerow([ip, ts, protocol, portNum, "".join(text)])
```

Comment: I'm sure this helps quite a bit. What about adding the condition to remove certain characters from each string in the list?

Comment: Basically a faster way to do this: text.append(str(str(k).replace('_','-') + ": "+str(v).strip("[]").strip("\"\'") + "\r\n"))

Comment: yeah, anything on the appended string won't be an issue.